# Creating rows of buttons

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to Android development, so bear with me.  I'm creating an app that features many calculations and formulas for weather, distance, speed, etc.  Anyway, I'm looking to create the main menu with rows of buttons similar to how the iPhone does it, i.e. you press one button row and it takes you to the next page of a rows of buttons.

Sort of like:

[image: http://joomlart.s3.amazonaws.com/images/templates/jd_purity_preview/home_iphone_menu.jpg]

Is this done using layouts and controls or a menu?

Comment: look into the android actionbar. you never want to duplicate iphone ux on android. NEVER.

Comment: I'm not sure an actionbar is what I'm looking for.  I basically want a menu that takes me to another menu that takes me to another menu that takes to the actual calculator (for wind speed, for example).  So what I really end up with is a tree of menus with the leaves being each individual calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a list view. I did this where you would have a list of items, similar to your home, About Drupal, Typography, etc., and then when the user clicked on one of those buttons, you would be taken to a detail page, or in Android's case, another `Activity`. Here is a great tutorial that will show you how to implement the list view:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking this too; however, can I use this with a ScrollView?  The menu needs to be scrollable and I don't want to have space between the buttons.  It should kind of look like Android's setting menu.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about the scrollable part, that will happen on it's own, as in the listview is scrollable. The user will be able to scroll and see the entire list. It will do everything that you want. I did it on my app and it worked well. If you like I can post a pic of my list view?

Comment: No, I think I got the idea.  Thanks though!  However, after looking at your link it seems like it's a lot of code just to do something so simple.

Comment: Yeah, there is a bit to setting up the listView, however, doing something like creating a set of buttons, wrapped in layouts, may be a similar amount of code. But as I have not done that, I'm not certain. You will find with Android, a lot of things that seem simple, aren't as simple as you suspect.  Best of luck :)